# Is there a more efficient way to Iterate unique pairs of indices and create measurement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

i find it hard to efficiently iterate unique unordered pairs of security indices and create a measure based on the two.
I would like to create measures of 'shared weights' like this:

[image]

where i and j represents a unique unordered pair of securities from a portfolio f in a dataframe like this:

| portflio number | month | Value of shares held | security id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2006-05-31 | xxxx.00 | 45245E10 |
| 1000 | 2006-05-31 | xxxx.00 | 44701110 |
| 1000 | 2006-05-31 | xxxx.00 | 3138WGGZ |
| 1000 | 2006-06-31 | xxxx.00 | 45245E10 |
| 1000 | 2006-06-31 | xxxx.00 | 3138WGGZ |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

S*F is the value of share held.

I currently create dataframe row by row. and here is a loop for each portfolio. ( The cold would be extremely slow if I add another loop "for n in range(len(share.porflio.unique())" and then sum by portfolio for each pair.)

```
columns = ['PORTNO','MONTH','a','b','Val']
store=DataFrame(columns = columns)
count1 = 0
count2 = 0
for t in share.MONTH:

    temp = share[share['MONTH']==t]
    for i in range(len(temp)): 
        data = pd.DataFrame({columns[0]:"",
                 columns[1]:"",
                 columns[2]:"",
                 columns[3]:"",
                 columns[4]:"",
                },index=[0])
        store = store.append(data,ignore_index=True)
        store.iloc[count1+count2,1] = temp.iloc[1,0]
        store.iloc[count1+count2,1] = t
        store.iloc[count1+count2,2] = temp.iloc[i,3]
        for j in range(len(temp)-i-1):
            store.iloc[count1+count2,3] = temp.iloc[i+j+1,3]
            store.iloc[count1+count2,4] = temp.iloc[i,2]+temp.iloc[i+j+1,2] 
            data = pd.DataFrame({columns[0]:"",
                 columns[1]:"",
                 columns[2]:"",
                 columns[3]:"",
                 columns[4]:"",
                },index=[0])
            store = store.append(data,ignore_index=True)
            count2 = count2+1
        count1 = count1+1
```

It is too slow. Is there a more efficient way to loop.

Comment: What's your question? Where did your attempts fail at?

Comment: nobody is going to download data to answer this question, please post sample data as code as well as your attempts to solve this problem

Comment: I have put my code on. Not sure how to post data like code

Comment: is my question still not clear? mp answer...